# Remove an item from my CustomArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Firstly, sorry for my english, I am french.

So, I have a CustomArrayAdapter (ReservationAdapter), and I would remove an item from this class. I have tried many things, but they didn't work.

```
public class ReservationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Reservation> {
public ReservationAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Reservation> reservations) {
    super(context, 0, reservations);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    Reservation reservation = getItem(position);

    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    ReservationHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ReservationHolder();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reservation_fragment, parent, false);

        holder.date = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateReserv);
        holder.imgDelete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.less);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ReservationHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    holder.date.setText(reservation.date);
    holder.imgDelete.setOnClickListener(deleteReservListener);

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}

private View.OnClickListener deleteReservListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Where I try to remove an item
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

public static class ReservationHolder {
    private EditText date;
    private ImageButton imgDelete;
}
```

Comment: pass a bollean and make the thingg workable and donot forget to dd notifydatasetchanget()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the item from `reservations` and then call `notifyDataChanged()`.

Before of all you have to implement a `OnItemClickListener` on your `ListView` (outside of your adapter, of course):

```
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemCLickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            reservations.remove(i);
            ((ReservationAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataChanged();
        }
    }
```

e voilà

Answer (score 0):

It works, merci !
Meanwhile, I'm still looking for a solution, and have find this :

```
holder.date.setText(reservation.date);
    holder.imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            remove(reservation);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

I just put the OnClickListener into the GetView method.
Thanks again ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add position vatiable in your ReservationHolder, and also construcror as:

```
public ReservationHolder(int position)
{
    this.position = position;
}

public int getCurrentPosition()
{
    return position;
}
```

and in getView(): ReservationHolder holder = new ReservationHolder(position);

Change your method:

```
private View.OnClickListener deleteReservListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Where I try to remove an item
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
};
```

to:

```
private View.OnClickListener deleteReservListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Where I try to remove an item

    ReservationHolder holder = (ReservationHolder)v.getTag();
    reservations.remove(holder.getCurrentPosition());

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
};
```